# Update Apache2 to 2.4 on Debian 6

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-squeeze

I just updated my PHP to latest version using dotdeb

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
```

Is there anything like dotdeb repositories for apache2 for Debian 6? I searched google for repositories but could not find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Apache 2.4 is currently only available on Jessie (testing) and sid (unstable). But it isn't really difficult to use the package on squeezy (or wheezy) without apt-pinning.

1. Download the source code from [here](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.10-8.dsc) and go in the directory:

   ```
   dget -x -u http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.10-8.dsc
   cd apache2-2.4.10/
   ```
2. Check the build dependencies (`dpkg-checkbuilddeps`) and install all listed packages
3. Now you can try to compile the package (see the link below for other options you can do before building):

   ```
   dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
   ```
4. The packages should have been build successfully to the parent directory. You can now install them on your machine.

Here is a complete reference: https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation

Answer (score 0):

You can list all available versions of a package and install the desired one or latest:

You need to do the following:

```
apt-cache showpkg <pachagename>
```

The above command will display list of available versions for this package. Then select the needed version and do the following.

```
apt-get install <packagename>=<complete version name>
```

Example:

```
apt-cache showpkg apache2
apt-get install apache2=2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, there isn't. It's available in Debian Jessie (testing) only at this point.

If you really need apache 2.4 I would recommend using jessie altogether for your machine's distribution instead of squeeze if possible to avoid having a mixed sources environment which would put you in a less-commonly used and less supported configuration.

Otherwise if there is a specific reason that makes you want to use 2.4 perhaps there's a workaround to update your php files or other to make it work in apache 2.2 and stay on squeeze.

But if you really want to go into a mixed sources environment it's possible using apt pinning, that will involve 2 steps:

- Adding sources of jessie to your /etc/apt/sources.list
- Adding a pinning preference in /etc/apt/preferences

Here's more information about it: https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences

Note that you might be faced with new apt dependency issues as your machine updates evolve and you install apache modules with mixed dependencies to 2.2 or 2.4. If it's an acceptable complication for your needs you could go ahead with it.